# Generating moving shape

Tags: javascript, python, animation, shapes

I am planning on coding this is python, though I'm not 100% sure yet this is the right solution. Maybe javascript would be better.

I have a questionnaire displayed question by question to a user, and for each question, the user enters an answer on a scale from 1 to 5. The program calculates different variables as the user inputs more and more answers.

The program then internally outputs a radial chart data. And this is where I'm stuck. I need the program to actually output graphically a "radial chart morph."

As the user enters the data, a shape like this is wiggling, like a jelly piece.

[image]

The program need to generate it, and constantly animate it, while the different colored layers are evolving.

How is the shape generated? Here is the theory:

Each answer from 1 to 5 has an impact on 5 different variables that are used to generate the shape.

[image]

So as the user inputs variables, the center might get bigger, or smaller, the red layer gain in size, or decrease in size... This happens live, it is a live animation and interpretation of the results.

And we don't have the desired shape yet. Then, the shape is filled with a color palette, and its edges are rounded:

[image]

Finally, the shape is constantly animated with a little moving jelly effect, like a cell.

And then, the second big part of the work is that we need to output this on a 20x20 LED matrix, like so (example with another cell):

[image]

What would be the best language to code that? It is essentially an animation evolving as the user inputs variables. Also, what libraries do you recommend, and do you have any code, links, functions, that could help me achieve that?

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: javascript is most suitable for this,  you can use some charting libraries like d3 js and it supports animation. For rendering 20X20 image you can use canvas to image library.

Comment: Yes indeed I did hear of D3 js. I found for instance this: https://lmgonzalves.github.io/jelly/ except I can't seem to have the shape constantly gently wiggling.  That would be a good start.